# building a binary tree from preorder and inorder traversals

Tags: c++

so, i wrote this code for the given problem on leetcode to construct a binary tree from given preorder and inorder traversals. its running fine when separately testing test cases but shows a runtime error on submitting for the same input that i tested.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int Search(vector<int> arr,int start, int end, int key){
        
        for(int i= start; i<= end; i++){
            if(arr[i]== key)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    TreeNode* solution(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder, int inorderStart, int inorderEnd){
        static int preorderIdx = 0;
        if(inorderStart> inorderEnd)
            return NULL;
        int data= preorder[preorderIdx];
        preorderIdx++;
        TreeNode* node= new TreeNode(data);
        
        if(inorderStart== inorderEnd)
            return node;
        
        int idx= Search(inorder,inorderStart, inorderEnd, data);
        node->left= solution(preorder, inorder, inorderStart, idx-1);
        node->right= solution(preorder, inorder, idx+ 1, inorderEnd);
        
        return node;
    }
    
    TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder) {
        int n= inorder.size(); 
        return solution(preorder, inorder, 0, n-1);
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the runtime error ? What is your tests input and output? Do you have a `main` ? Leetcode lets you not write a `main`, but for your own testing and debugging you should write a complete program

Comment: Leetcode will show the failed input and expected output, it's time to write a test with that input and debug it!

Comment: running seperate test cases going well but running several crashing suggests that `static int preorderIdx = 0;` is the problem. Don't use a static variable when it has to be reset for the next test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static int preorderIdx was the issue. Apologies for the incomplete question statement.
Thanks for the comments.